# Memory leak objective c table view reloading

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, memory, memory-leaks, reload

well i have an array which takes it's data from a plist file like this :

```
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Favorites.plist"];
    dataFavorites = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

and that dataFavorites Mutable Array reflects on a tableView which is editable so i add things on the plist file from other view controllers and i remove things from here. So my problem is how can i do that? Where i have to put that code so that when i add data to the plist file the array will reload the plist and refresh the table view. If i add them on the viewWillAppear then every new addition on the plist after a [self.tableView reloadData]; fixes my problem but gives me a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK fixed it just had to make the array copy in the .h file that solved both of my problems!